# Не могу запустить apache на redhat6

Tags: apache

Доброе утро.
После установки RedHat6 и apache, и при запуске apache выдает ошибку(файл выложил). В чем может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по скриншоту:

1. Это предупреждения, а не ошибки. По идее они не фатальны и apache должен запуститься
2. Похоже что apache запустился, и остался висеть на переднем плане (т.е. не возвратился в консоль, а вы его потом по Ctrl-C останавливали.

Comment: Да. после проверки apache запустился, но для дальнейшего не влияет на работу в apache или oracle?, так как БД тоже установлен.

Comment: Ничего не понял, кроме того что апач таки запустился.

Comment: Добрый день. Я имею ввиду ошибка "Warning: CORE_PATH=/usr/local/apache2/logs: Please configure a core file path using the sysctl utility" не влияет ли на работу apache или оракл?

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки - не должно влиять, но лучше всё же этот путь настроить как рекомендуется и жить без предупреждений.

Comment: Правда говоря я сам новичок в этой области а вот, что это за путь и что решить эту проблему

Answer (score 0):

если вы установили пакет *apache* из репозитория дистрибутива *redhat*, то запускать его следует (от имени *root*) командой вида:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

а останавливать:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd stop
```